# AngularCli Preconfigured build parameters

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In an AngularCli project, there is the command `ng build` which works fine in a dev environment, but for release I need a few extra options like

```
ng build -prod --base-href /serversubfolder/ -aot
```

Is there any way to add a sub script to angular cli so I can make a shorter command so I don't have to remember all these parameters. I.e.

```
ng build-release
```

Which would be equivalent to the first statement? or am I stuck making a batch file for now?

Comment: Add it to your `package.json`?

Comment: I did see the script section in there and tried both searching for how to use it and trying to figure it out by trial an error to no avail. Do you have an example of how to accomplish this in the package.json?

Comment: If you set it up with Angular CLI, it literally includes several entries in `scripts` that use `ng`. You just need to pick a name for the key then make your command above the value.

Comment: I added `"build-release": "ng build --prod --base-href /mysubfolder/ -aot"` to the scripts section and neither `ng build-release` nor `npm build-release` work. What am I missing?

Comment: `npm run build-release` - see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: that was it. Thanks

Comment: how do you make the cli accept --base-href as build param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure in your package.json file.

```
 "scripts": {
    "release":"ng build -prod --base-href /serversubfolder/ --aot"
  },
```

now you need enter

```
npm run release
```